# Is "return voidFunction()" valid code?

Tags: c++

I know the return statement is unnecessary and therefore can be avoided, but out of curiosity: is this valid code?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printNumber(int a)
{
    printf("Your number is: %d\n", a);
}

void doStuff()
{
    const int a = 12;
    return printNumber(a); // Is this valid, well-defined code?
}

int main()
{
    doStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles with no warnings using gcc and g++ 4.8.4:

`gcc -W -Wall -Werror -Wextra voidtest.cxx`

`g++ -W -Wall -Werror -Wextra voidtest.cxx`

It also runs as one would expect.

The question is tagged as C and C++ because I'd like to know if there's any difference in the answer for both languages.

Comment: Note you compile both times in C++ mode, you need to change extention or specify mode explicitly, g++ or gcc only differentiate libraries to link with.

Comment: For C it's a constraint violation, me thinks http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.6.4p1

Comment: It is not valid C. Please note that gcc is per default a non-standard compiler. If you tell it to be a standard conforming compiler, it will give you errors like it should `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors`

Comment: @Werner Henze: "Now valid"? It has *always* been valid in standard C++.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages. You could as well as about Java, C# or Brainfuck. There is no "C/C++". Just ask about one language per question. As you seem to compile as C++ only, I remove the C tag.

Comment: @AnT OK, maybe I mixed something up. I thought to remember that it once did not work with MSVC. I deleted my misleading comment.